# How to read 100 files and take the mean

Tags: list-manipulation

```
 list1 = OpenRead[
   "/home/sachin/Downloads/mam_code_evans/neutral_fix/n_t/nt.txt"];
 dataa = ReadList[list1, {Number, Number, Number}];
y1 = dataa[[All, 2]];
y2 = Table[1000, {i, 1, 100000}];
 y3 = Flatten[{y1, y2}];
```

I have 100 nt1.txt, nt2.txt, nt3.txt ... How to read these 100 files and save them in a 100 lists (in a loop) and then take average?

Comment: Maybe you can try the manipulation on list of strings. Use `Table` or some functions to build a list with elements are path and name of your data. Then finally map `OpenRead` over it.

Answer (score 1):

Read the data with [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) instead of reading/saving manually in variables:

```
Clear[data];
data[n_Integer?Positive] := data[n] = 
  ReadList["~/Downloads/mam_code_evans/neutral_fix/n_t/nt" <> 
           ToString[n] <> ".txt", {Number, Number, Number}]
```

Now we can load them and take the average (no need to save them to list; this is done internally in Mathematica):

```
Array[data, 100] // Mean
```

Comment: This is not of much use to me. I want using the way i asked in the question. Because then   i have to use the data somewhere else.

Comment: You can use `data[51]` fror example in any other place you want. Or store `A = Array[data, 100]`. Or...